# Optimising profit in responding to offers of customers

Tags: discrete-optimization

I have an linear algebra problem to solve. 
Currently I have n number of customer lists and m number of offers.

I have matrix (P) with dimension m x n. Elements of P indicates probability of responding to the relevant offer for each customers.

I need to find a matrix (N) with binary numbers (0,1) indicating whether an offer is made to a particular customer. It also dimension m x n

R is a column vector (mx1) representing revenues that can be made from each offers and C is also a column vector (mx1) representing costs generated from each offers.

How do I solve for the N which can give the maximum profit ?

**In summary I have**
P = probability (m x n)
R = Revenue (m x 1)
C = Cost (m x 1)
**I need to find**
N = binary variable (m x n) which will give the largest profit.
I think the profit is P(T) x N x (R-C)
where P(T) is transpose of P

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of 0-1 Knapsack problem. It's NP-complete, but there are a plenty heuristic and/or approximate algorithms for solving it.

Comment: Because I am looking for a matrix, is this multidimensional knapsack problem?